# MPDF - Position absolute and bottom 0

Tags: mpdf

I would like to fix a table in the footer, but it is when generating the PDF.

Using in the browser works, but not when the pdf is generated.

```html
<table width="100%" style="position:absolute; bottom:0">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th width="33%" style="border-top: 1px solid #000">Assinatura</th>
        <th width="33%"></th>
        <th width="33%"></th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
</table>
```

Comment: Your second foreach should be `foreach($ckl['children'] as $ckl2)`. Your first `json_decode()` should decode even the subarrays. Also, since it's an array, `echo` won't work. Try `print_r()`.

Comment: (I don’t think the way you are using the word “mount” here makes much sense. I have never heard of anyone “mounting” a foreach loop, or anything like that.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap the table in a DIV tag and absolute position the DIV.

```
<div style="position:absolute; bottom:0">

    <table width="100%">
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th width="33%" style="border-top: 1px solid #000">Assinatura</th>
            <th width="33%"></th>
            <th width="33%"></th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
    </table>

</div>
```